# How to remove columns from a csv file with PHP?

Tags: php, csv

I know the names of the columns I want to keep in the .csv file, but I am interested in removing all columns in the .csv which I don't recognize. How can php do this?

(The names of the columns are defined in the first row of the file.)

Comment: May I ask why?  Whenever I parse CSV files, I simply ignore the columns I don't need.

Comment: @Pickle The script I have written is returning duplicate columns errors when I try to import it into a database, I suppose I am more interested in getting rid of columns that I don't recognize to avoid duplication. I suppose there can be another approach to this.

Comment: A similar question worth looking at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814272/script-to-trim-7-columns-to-5-csv-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP use fgetcsv() to read in your CSV file, ignore the columns you want and then write back to a CSV file using fputcsv();

Answer (score 0):

Look at fgetcsv and fputcsv.  Read the contents, write the columns/data back out that you want.