# Script to trim 7 columns to 5 ( csv file )

Tags: php, csv

How can I trim these 7 columns down to 5 columns, by running some script of sorts.

I recall you can do this using regex / php but buggered if I can recall how we did it.

Example code ( of a GEO IP db ( 115,000 lines )

```
"3231296768","3231297023","ripencc","702518400","EU","EU","European Union"
"3231297024","3231297279","ripencc","441763200","EU","EU","European Union"
"3231297280","3231297535","ripencc","702518400","EU","EU","European Union"
"3231297536","3231297791","ripencc","702518400","EU","EU","European Union"
"3231297792","3231298047","ripencc","702518400","EU","EU","European Union"
"3231298048","3231298303","ripencc","702518400","EU","EU","European Union"
"3231298304","3231298559","ripencc","702518400","EU","EU","European Union"
```

I need to remove columns 3 and 4 from every line.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While jimw's answer is the best answer in general, if you want a pure PHP solution I would suggest the following:

```
$input = 'input.txt';
$output = 'output.txt';

if (false !== ($ih = fopen($input, 'r'))) {
    $oh = fopen($output, 'w');

    while (false !== ($data = fgetcsv($ih))) {
        // this is where you build your new row
        $outputData = array($data[0], $data[1], $data[4], $data[5], $data[6]);
        fputcsv($oh, $outputData);
    }

    fclose($ih);
    fclose($oh);
}
```

Comment: thanks @cbuckley appreciate your code, will play with both versions. Really appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Note that this removes any enclosing quotes unless they are deemed necessary, so that may be a factor in deciding the most suitable version for you.

Comment: Shame about the Inverted Commas. Hadnt noticed that comment, apologies.

Answer (score 4):

From 'a script of sorts' and 'regex/PHP', I infer that you just want this done, and don't care what language is used. If you're on *nix:

```
cut -d, -f1,2,5,6,7 file.csv
```

'cut' is a standard unix command-line utility, found on everything from OS X to AIX. The arguments I've used are:

```
-d, # this sets the 'delimiter' to a comma, for CSV

-f1,2,5,6,7 # this selects which fields to print
```

So together, it takes a file where each line consists of fields separated by commas and prints out fields one to five of it.

The same effect can be achieved in any programming language. I don't know PHP very well, so I won't attempt to produce it in PHP.

Edit: From the PHP docs, adapted slightly:

```
function apply_quotes($string) {
  return '"'.$string.'"';
}
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $data = array_map("apply_quotes", $data);
        echo join(",", array($data[0], $data[1], $data[4], $data[5], $data[6]))."\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: Could you explain, that looks like my winning lottery numbers in HEX. We are on apache

Comment: Ok thanks, our php guy is away. Just emailed him, if i get a fix, will post the php answer. Thanks

Comment: I'd just like to add that both answers remove the wrong columns based on the OP's request, but +1 for suggesting cut.

Comment: Thanks for that, I've corrected all my examples. No doubt there's a neater way to do the PHP one...

Comment: I prefer this solution, I had to parse a 2 Gb file and after using `cut` I got a 100m file ... +1